# How master-detail records are synchronized/accessible in junction object?

Tags: lookup, relationships, master-detail, workflowoutboundmessage, junction-object

I have a Juction object `CaseJiraItemAssociation__c` which is have two master-detail relationship (on `Case__c` and `JiraItem__c` custom objects) and I have one outbound message (end point) on `JiraItem__c` object and that outbound message end point is taking `JiraItem__c` fields as input parameters.

Now my question is I have one field called `HostingType` in `Case__c` object and I need to pass this as input parameter to end point created on `JiraItem__c` custom object along with `JiraItem__c` fields, how can I do this? much appreciated your help.

Comment: A junction object defines a many-to-many relationship. How are you envisioning picking which Case's field value you want?

Comment: junction object use to define a many-to-many relationship, If you want to pass the only HostingType field then you can add this field on JiraItem__c object and whenever the record gets created with JiraItem__c use case__c object's condition to fill the HostingType field.  So that you can directly pass the field as input.Hope this makes some sense.

Comment: Thank you @David and Rahul, Problem here is CaseJiraItemAssociation__c object is a Junction Object which is having two master-detail relationships Case__c and JiraItem__c. in background they are creating JiraItem__c record (Only Id and Name field) and storing that Id and CaseId in CaseJiraItemAssociation__c junction object but somewhere all fields of JiraItem__c object is updating with values which I couldn't able to find where exactly and I have HostingType field in Case which I need to copy to JiraItem__c object through CaseJiraItemAssociation__c junction object, can anyone help me pls?

Comment: @Manjunath Your data model is understood. You did not answer the question posed above.

Comment: @David I have HostingType__c (formula) field in Case object and that needs to copied in to HostingTypeJira__c field in JiraItem__c object. and there is a junction object CaseJiraItemAssociation__c to link these two object each other. and when ever there is an insert/update to a junction object? JiraItem__c object is also updating with the current values which I don't know where exactly they are doing this (checked in triggers, workflow rules and process builders)